# asp.net web forms + sql server with angular.js and ajax (Retrieving Data)

Tags: angularjs

I'm having problem about using Angular.js with Ajax in retrieving the data from sql server database.

Here is my code:

**Employee.aspx:**

```
<div ng-controller="EmpCtrl" ng-init="getEmployee()">
    <table border="1" style="text-align: center; margin-left: 410px;" >           
        <tr  ng-repeat="item in items" >
         <td>
                {{item._empID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._firstname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._lastname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._address}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._city}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._pincode}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._state}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._country}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**script.js:**

```
demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);
demoApp.controller('EmpCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getEmployee = function () {
        var _employee = [];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               _employee = response.d;
               $scope.items=_employee;
               console.log($scope.items);
            }

        });

    }
});
```

Whenever I run the project I get data on the console log But the problem is it is not displaying on the table, Only when i hit/click the button there was the time the first data on the console log will be display but the data on the console log on will become 2. and when the click again the button, the second record will now be display and the data on the console log will now 3.

**How can I display the data when after the Page load without clicking the button?**

Plaese help me... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem: you are using angular an doing the reuqest with jQuery. How to solve this:

insted of $.ajax you should use $http.post or even better $http.get - because you only retrieve data:

```
$http.get('WebService.asmx/GetEmployeeDetails').then(function(result){
   $scope.items = result.data;
})
```

Why did your code not working? The ajax results comes in out of the angular digest loop. So you will see the results not before the next digest loops runs. In your example this is the case if you click the button.

You can run the digest loop manually if you put your code in a $apply block:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.items=_employee;
});
```

But this is not necessary if you are using the $http service.

Comment: Thanks Michael! the first data was displayed after the page load when i used this code:  the $apply, thank you very much..!

Comment: @user3274033 yes, but i've hoped you would use the angular way :)

Comment: the $http.get doesn't work. it doesn't even return data. i don't know why, maybe i don't know how to use it. can you help me to or teach me how to use this technique? please...

Comment: @user3274033 have a look at the edited post - i have changed it to use the promise api. may be console.log(result) so you will see what you get.

Comment: I'm sorry Micheal... your right i just forgot to put the console.log. but i got this error on the console log: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500(Interval Server Error)**. I dont know this kind of error. please help me. thank you in advance...

Comment: this a an error on your server side. may be there are some more informations. because you are using post it could be that get is not implemented - but i am not sure...

Comment: I got result by using POST but the data is not in JSON format. maybe that's the reason why it is not displaying on the table.